# List 'areas' used in TFS project

Tags: c#, tfs, workitem

I've been playing about with the WorkItem objects from the Microsoft.TeamFoundation schemas in C#, but was wondering if anyone knows how I would refer to an object of type 'Area' or, for that matter, 'Iteration'.

It seems that these are treated as objects in TFS, but I haven't come across any information on how to refer to these in C#.

You can filter WorkItems by [Area] or [Iteration] using WIQL, but what if I wanted to populate a ComboBox with all Areas or Iterations?

Also, how can I view the database structure of my workplace's TFS project?

Thanks guys,

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this Blog Post](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2009/01/30/tfs-api-part-9-get-area-iteration-programmatically.aspx). There's sample code and a demo.

Here's a quick [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) Query that should do the job (download [VS2010](http://sdrv.ms/MKIvNx) / [VS2012](http://sdrv.ms/MKIrxg)):

```
void Main()
{
    const String CollectionAddress = "http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/MyCollection";
    const String ProjectName = "MyProject";

    using (var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(
        new Uri(CollectionAddress)))
    {
        tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();
        var server = tfs.GetService<ICommonStructureService>();

        var projectInfo = server.GetProjectFromName(ProjectName);
        var nodes = server.ListStructures(projectInfo.Uri).Dump();

        // You should be able to re-factor this with "Iteration"
        // for getting those too.
        var nodesXml = server.GetNodesXml(
            nodes
                .Where(node => node.Name == "Area")
                .Select(node => node.Uri).ToArray(),
            true);

        var areaPathAndId =
            XElement.Parse(nodesXml.OuterXml)
            .Descendants("Node")
            .Select(xe => new 
            { 
                Path = xe.Attribute("Path").Value, 
                ID = xe.Attribute("NodeID").Value, 
            })
            .Dump();        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dave. Since I don't have any experience with LINQ, I've started with the link you posted. Managed to get it working but only for the top layer of the hierarchy. I'm pulling my hair out trying to get to the child nodes, e.g. for iteration: Releases/1/1.0/1.01. I may come back here for more help.